# Visual Studio Code won't open .py, .ipynb files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed with the Python extension. When I try to open a .py or .ipynb file from the Windows File Explorer with VSCode, nothing opens and I get the windows "ding" sound instead (the same sound you get when a popup prevents you from interacting with other apps until you dismiss the popup). I tried user settings with and without file.associations, but either case did not work. Everything seems to work fine when from VSCode I choose File>>Open Folder and then browse to the .py or .ipynb file. Any idea why this is happening?

```
{
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "selection",
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "python.linting.pycodestyleCategorySeverity.E": "Information",
    "python.linting.pycodestyleCategorySeverity.W": "Information",
    "editor.minimap.showSlider": "always",
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 100,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "[xml]": {},
    "python.dataScience.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "[jsonc]": {},
    "editor.minimap.size": "fill",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "python.dataScience.textOutputLimit": 0,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.py": "python",
        "*.ipynb": "python",
        "*.pyt": "python"
    },
    "python.pythonPath": "c:\\my\\env\\Python.exe",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

Comment: Open cmd and type code ., then press enter, can you get vscode opened? Have you installed python extension in vscode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that shell file associations are set up with VS Code by default. files.associations setting is just to tie file extensions to the type of code inside visual studio code itself. If you right-click on a .py file do you see an option Open With=>Visual Studio Code? That option should be available to open it in VS Code.

If you want that to be default you can right click it in the shell and pick Open With=>Choose another app to select VSCode as the default app to open that item with.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your response. I'm not exactly sure what prevented me from opening the .py and .ipynb files but after a restart it seems to be working. I was using Open With >> Visual Studio Code and also checked the Context Click .py file >> Properties to make sure the default was VSCode. This wasn't the first time I had seen this problem with VSCode, so I was hoping someone else has experienced it and may have found the cause.

Comment: I have also experienced this problem. I was unable to open a .py file with VS Code yesterday regardless of how I tried. (Specifying the file on the VS Code command line didn't work. Using File|Open within VS Code itself didn't even work: No error was reported, but a new editor tab for the file simply did not appear). After a restart, it suddenly started working fine.